# How do I center a paragraph in Word using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and coding in vb.net and importing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word . I am using the following code to create a one page Word document with only two lines. How can I center, both vertically and horizontally these two lines? Also, is there a way to put both lines, with a line break in between, in one paragraph rather than using two? I am very new to this type of programming so please be specific. Thanks.

```
    Private Sub CreateTitlePage2()

    Dim wdApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Dim wdPara1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph
    Dim wdPara2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph

    wdDoc.Application.Visible = False

    wdPara1 = wdDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    wdPara1.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
    wdPara1.Range.Font.Bold = True
    wdPara1.Range.Text = "BINDER DOCUMENT"
    wdPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    wdPara2 = wdDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    wdPara2.Format.SpaceBefore = WdVerticalAlignment.wdAlignVerticalCenter
    wdPara2.Range.Font.Bold = True
    wdPara2.Range.Text = "Created:    " + formattedDate2
    wdPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    wdDoc.SaveAs(binderNameDoc)
    wdDoc.Close()
    wdApp.Quit()

End Sub
```

Comment: Surely this is something you could have researched before asking here.  Can you show what you've researched?  Otherwise, your question will probably get down votes.

Comment: The code sample shows the results of some of my research, neither of which is working. For the first paragraph, I try using the Paragraph.Format alignment and setting WdVerticalAlignment as wdAlignParagraphCenter. For the second paragraph, I try setting Format.SpaceBefore to the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ross: It would help if you'd describe HOW it's "not working". However...

WdVerticalAlignment is not valid applied to a paragraph object, I'm surprised you're not getting a compiler error. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224305(v=office.11).aspx.

If you want to center something vertically on the page then it must be done via the PageSetup object and then it will apply to the entire *SECTION*. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838676.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If you document is really only the one page, as you say, then you don't need to worry about the SECTION part as the document will have only the one.

RE Line break: Insert ANSI 11 character (vbVerticalTab) for a line break (what you get when pressing Shift+Enter in the Word application).